# ¿Cómo hago para no abrir mas de un tab con en mismo nombre en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo una app de angular donde todo se maneja dentro de la misma ruta /app, y para visualizar el contenido de mi app uso los tabs de angular/material@14.0.0 y necesito que cuando se intente abrir un tab que ya existe este no lo permita abrir y que además se posicione en el tab que el usuario intento abrir, estas validaciones ya la realice y relativamente todo esta funcionando pero al intentar abrir muchas cosas o al usarla mucho se descontrola rápidamente y deja de funcionar a como debería.

```
addTab(tabName: string) {
  let filtro: Array<any> = this.tabs.filter((element) => {
    return element.tabName == tabName;
  })
  let busqueda = filtro.find(obj => {
    return obj
  })
  if (filtro.length === 0 ) {
    this.casosParaAbrirTab(tabName)
  }
  else {
    console.log("no esta vacio");
    if (busqueda.tabName == tabName) {
      console.log("hay una ventana con el mismo nombre", busqueda);
      this.selected.setValue(busqueda.selector.length);
    }
  }
}
```

Esta es la función recibe el nombre del tab que se desea abrir, luego filtra al array que contiene todos los tabs abiertos y si la búsqueda esta vacía, significa que ese tab aun no existe, y si no existe pues abro un nuevo tab, en caso de que la búsqueda devuelva un objeto pues este verifica si tiene el mismo nombre que el que estoy queriendo abrir, y luego me manda a la posición de ese tab al que estoy intentando abrir, dejo aqui un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxekdj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) muy completo para que lo puedan analizar de manera mas detallada, aunque capaz algo se me escapa, le agradezco su ayuda de antemano ;)

**Ejemplo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bxekdj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**Vista previa:** https://angular-ivy-bxekdj.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes se encuentra en la siguiente línea:

```
this.selected.setValue(busqueda.selector.length);
```

Ya que **`busqueda.selector`** en realidad es una función, por lo mismo no puedes hacerle un *length*.

Ahora bien lo que puedes hacer es simplemente utilizando un [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) encontrar la posición donde se encuentra el tab que ya existe en tu array *tabs*, de la siguiente forma: `this.tabs.indexOf(busqueda)`, esto retornará el índice del tab que ya tienes almacenado en la variable *busqueda*.

Solo quedaría setearlo a la variable *selected* de la misma forma que estabas haciendo anteriormente pero utilizando el cambio mencionado, quedaría así:

```
this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.indexOf(busqueda));
```

Finalmente el código que tienes como ejemplo en tu pregunta quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
addTab(tabName: string) {
  let filtro: Array<any> = this.tabs.filter((element) => {
    return element.tabName == tabName;
  })
  let busqueda = filtro.find(obj => {
    return obj
  })
  if (filtro.length === 0 ) {
    this.casosParaAbrirTab(tabName)
  }
  else {
    console.log("no esta vacio");
    if (busqueda.tabName == tabName) {
      console.log("hay una ventana con el mismo nombre", busqueda);
      this.selected.setValue(this.tabs.indexOf(busqueda));
    }
  }
}
```

Y para finalizar, vi que en la consola salia un error porque te falta importar el módulo **BrowserAnimationsModule**, esto lo puedes hacer en el archivo **`app.module.ts`**, quedaria mas o menos así:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule, // <=== Este es el módulo que te faltaba
  ],
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta!